# Embedding directx app with C++ Builder dll

Tags: dll, directx, c++builder

I want to add some functionality to another directx application(game). I am creating new thread in DllMain, in thread i create my TForm1 and use its method ShowModal(). And it works! But the problem is - the interface of my app looks like Win95(flat) style. Any ways to solve it? I think i need to set some WINAPI settings, before creating my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to either add the TXPManifest to your form (from the Win32 Tool palette) or go to the project options and set "Enable runtime themes" under Application.